# this.transitionToRoute not working in my controller Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using a controller to read the value selected on a drop down menu, take in parameters of some input fields and then save the record.  It creates the record and takes in the information just fine.  My problem lies when I try to transition to another page at the end of the action.  I keep getting the error: `Cannot read property 'transitionToRoute' of undefined`

I am completely stumped.  Any ideas?

Here is my controller code:

```
var teamId;
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    auth: Ember.inject.service(),
    actions: {
        onSelectEntityType: function(value) {
         console.log(value);
         teamId = value;
         return value;
      },
      createProcess: function(processName, processDescription) {
        var currentID = this.get('auth').getCurrentUser();
        let team = this.get('store').peekRecord('team', teamId);
        let user = this.get('store').peekRecord('user', currentID);
        let process = this.get('store').createRecord('process', {
            team: team,
            user: user,
            name: processName,
            description: processDescription
        });
        process.save().then(function () {
        this.transitionToRoute('teams', teamId);
      });
    }

    }
});
```

Here is the corresponding route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    auth: Ember.inject.service(),
    model: function() {
        var currentID = this.get('auth').getCurrentUser();
        return this.store.find('user', currentID);
    }
});
```

Comment: `this` is undefined inside the callback function. There are dozens if not hundreds of posts here on SO about this. The easiest way around this is to use an arrow function, as in `.then(() => this.transitionToRoute`. Another approach is to set a `self` variable at the top of the function and use that.

Comment: One correction, there are likely thousands, but to be fair, it's probably the most common issue people have with JavaScript.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097598/nesting-functions-in-js/37097783#37097783)

Comment: What's with the downvote? Looks a good question to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have clear understanding about **this** keyword in Javascript. The keyword this only depends on how the function was called, not how/when/where it was defined.

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}

// normal function call
foo(); // `this` will refer to `window`

// as object method
var obj = {bar: foo};
obj.bar(); // `this` will refer to `obj`

// as constructor function
new foo(); // `this` will refer to an object that inherits from `foo.prototype`
```

Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to learn more.

You can cache the **this** in normal variable this and then access inside the call back.

```
var self = this;

process.save().then(function () {
  self.transitionToRoute('teams', teamId);
});
```

ECMASCript 6 introduced arrow functions whose this is lexically scoped. Here, this is looked up in scope just like a normal variable.

```
process.save().then(() => {
  this.transitionToRoute('teams', teamId);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  It helped a lot in my understanding of **this**