# "this" is undefined in torii-adapter in ember

Tags: ember.js, torii

I am trying to store some data post login inside store. Below is code of my torii-adapter

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import {createToken} from 'myapp/utils/app-utils';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),

  open: function(authentication){
    let authorizationCode = authentication.authorizationCode;
    let token = createToken();
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      console.log(authentication);
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/getUserInfoWuthAuthCode.php',
        data: { 'code': authorizationCode,token:token},
        success: Ember.run.bind(null, resolve),
        error: Ember.run.bind(null, reject)
      });
    }).then(function(data){
      let user = data.user[0];
      this.set('storage.token',token); //this is undefined
      return {
        user: user
      };
    });
  }

});
```

Error i am getting is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined".
I am injecting the store service as well. Could you please tell me what exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: since you are in `ember-cli` I would recommend you to use an arrow function, this won't override your `this` context. I recommend you to inform yourself how `this` in JS works, and why we have arrow functions. Also you don't have to manually create the first promise, just return the result of `Ember.$.ajax` and use `Ember.RSVP.resolve()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is not defined in your current context. Assign it to another varible.

```
  open: function(authentication){
    let authorizationCode = authentication.authorizationCode;
    let token = createToken();
    let that = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      console.log(authentication);
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/getUserInfoWuthAuthCode.php',
        data: { 'code': authorizationCode,token:token},
        success: Ember.run.bind(null, resolve),
        error: Ember.run.bind(null, reject)
      });
    }).then(function(data){
      let user = data.user[0];
      that.set('storage.token',token); //this is undefined
      return {
        user: user
      };
    });
  }
```

To get further understanding and to see different options (such as **fat arrow** or **bind** method), have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097598/nesting-functions-in-js/37097783#37097783).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use ES6 arrow function, so that you do not need to assign `this` other another variable.

```
 open: function(authentication){
    let authorizationCode = authentication.authorizationCode;
    let token = createToken();
    let that = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(authentication);
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/getUserInfoWuthAuthCode.php',
        data: { 'code': authorizationCode,token:token},
        success: Ember.run.bind(null, resolve),
        error: Ember.run.bind(null, reject)
      });
    }).then((data) => {
      let user = data.user[0];
      that.set('storage.token',token);
      return {
        user: user
      };
    });
  }
```

Ember-cli will help you to convert ES6 to ES5 to make it compatible for most browsers.