# Ember 2, call functions in route using Ember.run.debounce

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, debouncing

I'm in a route called "**game**".

In an action I call Ember.run.debounce for a function, but in that function I can't call other functions.

**app/routes/game.js**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    ...
  },

  saveGame: function () {
    this.save().then(() => {
      this.updateOtherGames(); //<------ ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR
    })
  },

  updateOtherGames(game) {

  },

  actions: {
    playGame(game) {
      ...
      Ember.run.debounce(game, this.saveGame, 5000);
    }
  }
})
```

Why I can't call `updateOtherGames`?

Why `this` in the `saveGame` function is only referring to `game` nd not the route?

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage of `debounce` is:

```
Ember.run.debounce(this, this.saveGame, game, 5000);
```

Here is [the API](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce).

After correcting it, calling `updateOtherGames` will work.

Comment: Do you agree with me that the documentation on this point is a bit confusing? I will try your method soon.

Comment: Definition of `target` is _target of method to invoke_. At sample code, `target` shown as `context`. Yes a bit confusing. Actually, `target` means who will be `this` in that function context.

Comment: A guy on ember forum answered this: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-2-call-functions-in-route-using-ember-run-debounce/12776/2 What is correct? Your or this one?

Comment: Actually, it is same. That answer uses a fat arrow function call and passes the argument. Mine uses debounce 3th parameter... Both is ok.

Comment: For fat arrow have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097598/nesting-functions-in-js/37097783#37097783). This answer may help you to understand better.