# Ember, can't assign a variable inside an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

So I am trying to assign a variable, it runs ok if there is no ajax call but trying to assign the response does not work (response data is ok, I can console.log it)
Here is my component code, upon editing the objects array anywhere but in the ajax call it updates correctly.

```js
import Component from '@ember/component';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Component.extend({

  objects: [],

  actions: {
    loadObjects: function() {
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: <API URL>,
        type: "GET"

      }).then(function(resp) {
        this.set('objects', resp);
        console.log(resp);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Any idea? Been smashing my head for hours

EDIT: Working thanks to @Dmitry, here is the working solution

```js
import Component from '@ember/component';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Component.extend({

  objects: [],

  actions: {
    loadObjects: function() {
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: <API URL>,
        type: "GET"

      }).then(resp => {
        this.set('objects', resp);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know ember but my guess is that `this` inside `then` handler is set to `window`.  Try to use arrow function instead: `resp => {this.set('objects', resp);}`

Comment: Dmitry you rock man, it instantly worked, thanks!!

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097598/nesting-functions-in-js/37097783#37097783). Same problem, same solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot, I gave a +1